# React + Redux : How to display validation messages

Tags: reactjs, redux

I want to validate the dropdown value with the max count and display the error message by binding it to a html label on validation. Currently i am displaying it using alert.

my file "test.js"

```
render() {
    let testmethod = (criteriaType, e) => {
         switch(criteriaType)
            case("adults"): 
               if(e.target.value > MaxAdultCount) {
                  //display message
                  alert("Invalid Adult Count");
               }
            break;
        ............ // rest code
    }; 
}
```

Let me know if more details are required.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by building my own own validated dropdown field, see it here:

https://github.com/mi-squared/volunteer-portal/blob/master/client/src/components/dropdown-field.jsx

This component builds its own label in addition to the dropdown options. If the component's prop for errors contains the component's name, an error is rendered in the component label.

I hope this example can help.

Comment: Thanks Aron. I call my custom method inside onBlur() property of dropdown and want to bind the error message to a label which is defined somewhere else in the same page in another div. 
I tried related to your example, apology not able to visualise the concept. Can you help me.

Comment: If all components share a reference to an error map, one component can signal error for another component  by adding the target components Id to that map. Each component checks the error map for whether they should display an error.

Comment: I get it now Rachoac. Thanks

Comment: @Aron, in ur link, can you please explain what this line does

 getOptions: function () {
      if (this.props.formLists) {
        return this.props.formLists[this.props.fieldName.replace('data.q_', '').replace('session.', '')];
      } else {
        return [];
      }
    },

Sorry I am new to React and Redux, so bit confused.

Comment: Hi, basically can ignore the replace, change this return this.props.formLists[this.props.fieldName.replace('data.q_', '').replace('session.', '')];    .... to just this: return this.props.formLists[this.props.fieldName];